# How to validate an ActiveX Code as HTML5?

Tags: validation, activex

I know ... ActiveX ... blarghhh!

the normal code for using an OCX Object in HTML is:

```
<object id="ActiveX" 
        classid="CLSID:DF3748A3-7F0B-47E9-BB32-233E591CAD65" 
        width="140" height="140" 
        codebase="http://domain.com/ActiveX.cab#version=1,0,0,0">
</object>
```

but [HTML5 docs](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_object.asp) states that `codebase` and `classid` are no longer supported and that I should use `data` and `type` instead...

I can get that the `data` will hold the path to the `cab` file, but where do I stick the `classid` ?

```
<!-- OCX -->
<object id="ActiveX" 
        classid="CLSID:DF3748A3-7F0B-47E9-BB32-233E591CAD65" 
        width="140" height="140"
        data="http://domain.com/ActiveX.cab#version=1,0,0,0" 
        type="application/octet-stream">
</object>
```

works, but because I still have `classid` is still not a valid document :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a registry key that will map a mimetype to a CLSID and then you can just use the type="" attribute.

For more info, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I didn't get something ... that is done in the server that holds IIS or in every client?