# Visual Studio 2012 C# 3.5 Web App and Word Interop COM

Tags: javascript, c#, html, visual-studio-2012, office-interop

The main issue:  HTML5 does not support classid in object tag.

The details:

This is a rewrite of an old Visual Studio 2008 C# web app project.  I am rewriting everything using Visual Studio 2012 C# .net 3.5.  I am also using a nice modern responsive template in the new project, and it is using HTML5, jquery, bootstrap, etc.  This new app runs well in Chrome, FF, but not so well in IE...go figure.

One of the things this web app does is merge data into a word template file via COM and microsoft interop calls.  All that logic is compiled as a separate class library project and is deployed as a .DLL to the client browser.

So, when the user clicks a button on a page to generate a word document, the page that is returned from the server will have in it a Javascript call (or many calls) to the .DLL, which does all the work, and from the client pc.  The .DLL copies a word template file (somefile.doc) to a temp location, instantiates Word on the client pc, and directs Word to merge some data into the somefile.doc file into predefined bookmarks (customer info mostly).

This has worked fine for years in the old project / architecture and here are the basics of how it is implemented:

somepage.aspx head tag (actually using a masterpage, but for simplicity...):

```
<head>
    <object id="myWordX" classid="myWordX.dll#namespace.class" name="myWordX" VIEWASTEXT></object>
</head>
```

Javascript function that calls a method in the COM DLL passing 3 values:

```
function TestCallJS(param1, param2, param3) {
    try {
        if (myWordX) {
            myWordX.TestCall(param1, param2, param3);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(GetJSExceptionInfo('TestCall', e));
    }
}
```

C# code that builds Javascript block that will be sent back to the client browser to call the Javascript function above:

```
StringBuilder sbScript = new StringBuilder();

sbScript.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
sbScript.AppendFormat("TestCallJS('{0}','{1}', '{2}');", data1, data2, data3);
sbScript.Append("</script>");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "test", sbScript.ToString());
```

If you follow the logic above, when the request is made to the server, the code gets some data, builds the script with required param values, then that goes back to the client browser.  When the page is loaded into the browser, the TestCallJS javascript function calls the TestCall method in the COM DLL which does all of the word interop work.

The problem I am having is that HTML5 does not like the object tag.  If the tag as you see it above is placed into the head tag of the page, it complains about the following:

Validation (HTML5): Element 'object' cannot be nested within element 'head'.

Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'classid' is not a valid attribute of element 'object'.

And it complains about VIEWASTEXT saying it needs to be followed by an = sign and a value.

If I move the object tag to the body tag, it only complains about the classid and the VIEWASTEXT.

I have read that classid is no longer supported by HTML5, so what do I do to get this COM object to work with HTML5?

Thanks for taking the time to read this!  I have a huge library of methods in my COM object for manipulating Word doc templates, XML, TIF, XPS, sending emails, etc, from the client pc...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like there isn't an easy answer to this one. I found the following which talks about adding a custom mimetype which might work:

[How to validate an ActiveX Code as HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757358/how-to-validate-an-activex-code-as-html5)

Does the object still work even though the HTML5 validator gives an error?

Comment: Javascript throws this error:  myWordX.TestCall is not a function.  And that is with the object tag moved to within the body tag.

Comment: I have read that a lot of ppl switch to Office Open XML on the server, but I think that is another can of worms and perhaps means rewriting everything??

Comment: Is it possible to render the one page not in HTML5? Or does it need html5 other things?

Comment: Good suggestion, I am trying something like that now.  I have a fresh page, no master page, changed the DocType to older transitional, but am getting the same TypeError: myWordX.TestCall is not a function.  Still googling...

Comment: No, that project is on hold and I did not find resolution.  I may get back to it some day.